# how to get the cpu usage of past 10 minutes in python

Tags: python, psutil

I am  able to get current cpu usage details using  following code

```
import psutil as PSUTIL
PSUTIL.cpu_percent(interval=1)
```

My question is; how  can i get the past 10 minutes cpu usage details?

Comment: Don't think that would be possible, IMO. You could record it for ten minutes though, in a while loop with a timer, and then plot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the python script in background using cronjob 
 1)Open terminal and type crontab -e 
 2)Edit the file and write the following code to run the python script in         background

```
*/1 * * * * python /yourpath/yourpythonfile.py
```

3) Create yourpythonfile.py  and write the following code

```
import psutil as PSUTIL 
    with open('/yourpath/yourfile.txt', "a") as myfile:
       myfile.write(str(PSUTIL.cpu_percent(interval=1))+"%"'\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to:

1. Make a background task using the `threading` module, or system service/daemon. Something that works parallel to your main code;
2. Create a timer in the background task. At every timer's tick ask for cpu usage and write it into an array.
3. When main code needs `CPU` load stats, pass it from the background task by `IPC`, `files`, etc.

The exact solution depends on what tools can you use.

Comment: That is a logical and incredible idea. Can you further elaborate how would one approach this method in case of a simple Python program with several functions: A, B and C (for instance). How would a person go about getting these `stats` for all these 3 funcitons ?

Answer (score 1):

To measure CPU usage, you need to compare the usage at two given time; you can't get measure point from the past (except if you store it, as [@ajsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4215464/ajsp) suggested).

For example:

```
import psutil
import time

def calculate(t1, t2):
    # from psutil.cpu_percent()
    # see: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/__init__.py
    t1_all = sum(t1)
    t1_busy = t1_all - t1.idle
    t2_all = sum(t2)
    t2_busy = t2_all - t2.idle
    if t2_busy <= t1_busy:
        return 0.0
    busy_delta = t2_busy - t1_busy
    all_delta = t2_all - t1_all
    busy_perc = (busy_delta / all_delta) * 100
    return round(busy_perc, 1)

cpu_time_a = (time.time(), psutil.cpu_times())
# your code taking time
cpu_time_b = (time.time(), psutil.cpu_times())
print 'CPU used in %d seconds: %s' % (
    cpu_time_b[0] - cpu_time_a[0],
    calculate(cpu_time_a[1], cpu_time_b[1])
)
```

Or you could use `cpu_percent(interval=600)`; and if you don't want it to block other code in your script you might want to do it in a separate [thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

But as previously said, in both cases this won't go back in time; just measure CPU time from now to `interval`.

If you just need to keep track of your CPU usage and don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could use:

- http://www.rrdtool.org/ which provide tools to store and eventually graph metrics such as CPU time
- https://github.com/nicolargo/glances which could be daemonized and you would poll it to get the values you need
- http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/dstat/
- etc.

Those solutions can help you to save metrics from your system for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.getloadavg()` to find average load on the server during past 1, 5 & 15 minutes.

May be this turns out to be useful for what you intend to do.